# Windows Embedded wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-embedded

I have build a WPF media player application in c# .Net 4.0. I would like to take this WPF application and put it on a Windows Embedded operating system. This would take out all the things I don't need and just make a simple power on and my application loads. I know there will be a lot of work in order to make this happen and I'm just wondering if someone can point me to a good starting location. I've looked around a lot but haven't found a good tutorial on how to go about doing this or what version of windows embedded I would need etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Windows Embedded 8, it's basically full windows with lockdown features, thus any application that can run on normal windows will be able to run on it